# Excel Vba Index Match multiple criterias to return Exact match

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have a vba code that I will use to look for values that meet exact 2 criterias.
In most cases the vba returns the expected values
but if I change the criterias, or if I enter criterias that are not in the ranges I look into, the VBA returns a wrong value.
If the criterias are not met, I would prefer to have a text "CriteriasNotMet" shown as result in H2

My code is:

```
Sub IndexMatch()
myName = [F2]
mySubject = [G2]
mark = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index([StMark], _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myName, ([StName]), 0) + _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(mySubject, ([StSubject]), 0) - 1)

[H2] = mark

End Sub
```

Can anyone explain where I am doing something wrong ?

Thank you and god aften

Peter
Denmark

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.FunctionHere
```

throws a run-time error if something is wrong (such as no match found for example), whereas

```
Application.FunctionHere
```

will instead return either a result or an error value which you can test using `IsError()`

That doesn't help you with the `-1` adjustment, so you can't do this all in a single line of code: you need to test each return value before passing them to `Index()`

```
Sub IndexMatch()

    Dim subIndx, nmIndx, mark

    subIndx = Application.Match([G2], [StSubject], 0)
    nmIndx = Application.Match([F2], [StName], 0)

    If Not IsError(subIndx) And Not IsError(nmIndx) Then
        mark = Application.Index([StMark], nmIndx, subIndx - 1)
    Else
        mark = "No Match"
    End If

    [H2] = mark

End Sub
```